# Find the following probabilities using given ones

Tags: probability

I have to find the following probabilities in this exercise:

a) Find $P(A)$ when $P(A \cap B) = p_1$ and $P(A \cap \bar{B}) = p_2$

I think this is easy, but to make sure I am correct, I am posting the solution below, so please tell me if I am right or wrong:

$P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar{B}) = p_1 + p_2$

b) Find $P(\bar{A} \cap B)$ when $P(A)=p_1$ and $P(B)=p_2$

I did the following actions:

\begin{align*}
P(\bar{A} \cap B) &= P(B) - P(A \cap B) \\
P(\bar{A} \cap B) &= P(A \cup B) - P(A) \\
P(B) - P(A \cap B) &= P(A \cup B) - P(A) \\
P(B) - P(A \cap B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) - P(A)
\end{align*}

Everything here gets simplified, so I can't find anything.

c) Find $P(A \vert B)$ and $P(B \vert A)$ when $P(A)=p_1$, $P(B)=p_2$ and $P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B})=p_3$.

I have no idea about this one.

d) Prove that $P(B \vert A) \geq 1 - \frac{P(\bar{B})}{P(A)}$ and $P(B \vert A) \geq \frac{P(A) + P(B) - 1}{P(A)}$

I don't know how to solve this one too.

It would be awesome if you guys could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited your question pretty extensively to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); please check that I preserved everything correctly.

Comment: Thanks Dylan! Everything's correct!

Comment: @DylanSp, from the answers to the questions d)1) and d)2) I guess that OP means $A \vert B$ and not $A \ B$ (conditional probabilities). See my answer attempt.

Comment: @snitchben Can you clarify whether c) and d) are supposed to be set differences ($A \setminus B$) or conditional probabilities ($A \vert B$)?

Comment: It can only be conditional probabilities given what needs to be proven in question d)

Comment: c) and d) are supposed to be conditional probabilities. Sorry for any mistakes!

Comment: Question b) is unsolvable as is. We need more information. (Maybe $A$ and $B$ are independent, or $P(A\cup B)$ is given, for example?)

Comment: Hi @Farnight! Sorry for the late reply! No, nothing else is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to solve these exercises is **Bayes' rule**
$$ P(A \vert B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $$

---

For c) start from Bayes' rule and note that
$$P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$$
and 
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
you can then write

\begin{align}
 P(A \cap B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)\\
             &= P(A) + P(B) + P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) - 1
\end{align}
and finally
$$ P(A \vert B) = \frac{P(A) + P(B) + P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) - 1}{P(B)} $$
Use a similar reasoning for $P(B \vert A)$.

---

For d) 1) 
Start from Bayes ' rule
$$ P(B \vert A) = \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(A)} $$
and notice that
$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$$
so that 
\begin{align}
P(B \vert A) &= \frac{P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)}{P(A)} \\
             &= \frac{P(A) + (1-P(\bar{B})) - P(A \cup B)}{P(A)} \\
             &= \frac{P(A) - P(\bar{B}) - (P(A \cup B)-1)}{P(A)} \\
             &= {\color{blue}{1 - \frac{P(A \cup B)-1}{P(A)}}} - \frac{P(\bar{B})}{P(A)}
\end{align}
because $P(A \cup B) \leq 1$ and $P(A) \geq 0$ we have 
$$ \frac{P(A \cup B)-1}{P(A)} \leq 0 $$ 
hence
$$ {\color{blue}{1 - \frac{P(A \cup B)-1}{P(A)}}} {\color{red}{\geq 1}} $$
and going back to our formula for the conditional probability
\begin{align}
P(B \vert A) &= \left({\color{blue}{1 - \frac{P(A \cup B)-1}{P(A)}}}\right) - \frac{P(\bar{B})}{P(A)} \\
 &{\color{red}{\geq 1}} - \frac{P(\bar{B})}{P(A)} 
\end{align}

For d) 2)
Start from Bayes' rule
$$ P(B \vert A) = \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(A)} $$
and notice that
$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$$
Now since $P(A \cup B) \leq 1$
$$ P(B \vert A) = \frac{ P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) }{P(A)}  \geq  \frac{ P(A) + P(B) - 1 }{P(A)} $$

Comment: My pleasure, but please be careful with your notations. For instance the answer of JKnecht below is valid given your notation $A \backslash B$ (which means $A$ without $B$) instead of $A \vert B$ (which means $A$ conditionally on $B$): it is not the same thing at all!

Comment: The problem is that in Albania we use A/B to show A conditionally on B. Thanks for your advice anyway! Will have it mind the next time!

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to mark the answer as such if it has helped you so that 'the topic is closed'. Cheers.

Comment: I really want to mark the answer, but there's also point b) which I can't solve :)

Comment: Ah... sorry I didn't see that, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @snitchben You really should upvote and accept it anyway...after all its a three part question.

Comment: sure I will @JKnecht

Comment: As a matter of fact, are you sure you don't miss a piece of info for question b) like the probability of the intersection, or union, or the fact that the two sets of events are independent? If not, I fail to see the answer sorry.

Comment: No, the question is correct. Thanks very much anyway! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay then maybe you should state in your original post that you are OK with the questions c) and d) but b) is still bothering you. I am curious to see the answers because, for me, it is not doable as such. You need additional info. You are welcome ;)

Comment: @Quantuple I'm not sure how you got to the conclusion in d) 1). Could you please explain it to me? I mean how did you go back to the formula for the conditional probability

Comment: Do the colors help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Quantuple